# There is a documentation page or example for this android package?

Tags: android, annotations

There is an official documentation or examples? for this Official android package:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android/annotations

I can't find something about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download the JAR file for that artifact, you will notice that it contains only two things: [`SuppressLint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/SuppressLint.html) and [`TargetApi`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/TargetApi.html), both of which are documented.